# GCC ignores __attribute__((section("CCMRAM"))). How to fix?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm, ld

I am trying to use core-coupled memory (CCMRAM) of my cortex-m4 (STM32F407). It works fine with Keil MDK-ARM but gcc-arm-none-eabi ignores `__attribute__((section("CCMRAM")))`.

```
 #define configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE 1000*1024
 #define region1_HEAP_SIZE  (40*1024)
 #define region2_HEAP_SIZE  (configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE - region1_HEAP_SIZE)

 static uint8_t ucHeap1[ region1_HEAP_SIZE ]  __attribute__((section("CCMRAM")));
 static uint8_t ucHeap2[ region2_HEAP_SIZE ];
 const HeapRegion_t xHeapRegions[] =
 {
     { ucHeap1, sizeof(ucHeap1) },
     { ucHeap2, sizeof(ucHeap2) },
     { NULL, 0 } /* Terminates the array. */
 };
```

Manual https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes

According to manual I also tried to initialize `ucHeap1`

```
 static uint8_t ucHeap1[ region1_HEAP_SIZE ]  __attribute__((section("CCMRAM"))) = {0};
```

But does no effect.

Map-file contains nothing about `ucHeap1`. GCC compiles with no warnings about attribute. But fail to link because of:

```
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: avds.elf section `.bss' will not fit in region `RAM'
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: region `RAM' overflowed by 55032 bytes
```

These 55032 should be allocated in CCMRAM. But it tries to use RAM.
Please help me to understand what to do to make it work.

Linker script:

```
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)
_estack = 0x20000000 + 128K - 1;
_Min_Heap_Size = 0;
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x200;
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 1024K
  RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
  CCMRAM (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
}
SECTIONS
{
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)
    *(.text*)
    *(.glue_7)
    *(.glue_7t)
    *(.eh_frame)
    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;
  } >FLASH
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)
    *(.rodata*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >FLASH
  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;
    *(.data)
    *(.data*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;
  } >RAM AT> FLASH
  _siccmram = LOADADDR(.ccmram);
  .ccmram :
  {    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sccmram = .;
    *(.ccmram)
    *(.ccmram*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _eccmram = .;
  } >CCMRAM AT> FLASH
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    _sbss = .;
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >RAM
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }
  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Comment: Please create an [MCVE]. What is `HeapRegion_t`? `*(.ccmram)` but `.ccram` != `CCRAM`, no?

Comment: It is hard because of big enough context. Stm32 and cmsis and freertos all in one looks like a big enough project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.ccmram` section name is not `CCMRAM`. Note that sections with a leading dot should be by a small ignored convention left to implementations. So prefer just section names without leading dot.

Remove your `.ccmram : { ... }` and replace it by:

```
 .ccmram :   {
    .  = ALIGN(4);
    _sccmram = .;
    KEEP(*(CCMRAM))    # section is named CCMRAM __not__ .ccmram and __not__ .ccmram*
    . = ALIGN(4);  
    _eccmram = .;
 } >CCMRAM AT> FLASH
```

after that change:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc main.c -Wl,-T,./linker.ld --specs=nosys.specs && arm-none-eabi-nm ./a.out  | grep ucHeap
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.0/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol Reset_Handler; defaulting to 0000000008000000
10000000 d ucHeap1
20000434 b ucHeap2
```

Or alternatively you could change `__attribute__((section("CCMRAM")))` to `__attribute__((section(".ccmram")))` or to `__attribute__((section(".ccmram*")))` to match section names used in linker script.

Your `.bss` section could be overflowing nonetheless. As in my tests `configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE` macro was undefined, `region2_HEAP_SIZE` was `- 40*1024` which is negative so wraped around and resulted in a big positive number.

I tested with:

```
cat >Makefile <<EOF    
all:
    arm-none-eabi-gcc main.c -Wl,-T,./linker.ld --specs=nosys.specs && arm-none-eabi-nm ./a.out  | grep ucHeap
EOF

cat >linker.ld <<EOF
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)
_estack = 0x20000000 + 128K - 1;
_Min_Heap_Size = 0;
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x200;
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 1024K
  RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
  CCMRAM (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
}
SECTIONS
{
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)
    *(.text*)
    *(.glue_7)
    *(.glue_7t)
    *(.eh_frame)
    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;
  } >FLASH
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)
    *(.rodata*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH
  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >FLASH
  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;
    *(.data)
    *(.data*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  .ccmram :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sccmram = .;
    KEEP(*(CCMRAM))
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _eccmram = .;
  } >CCMRAM AT> FLASH
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    _sbss = .;
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >RAM
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }
  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
EOF

cat >main.c <<EOF
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
static uint8_t ucHeap1[ 10 ]  __attribute__((section("CCMRAM")));
static uint8_t ucHeap2[ 20 ];
typedef struct {
    uint8_t *p;
    size_t s;
} HeapRegion_t;
const HeapRegion_t xHeapRegions[] =
{
     { ucHeap1, sizeof(ucHeap1) },
     { ucHeap2, sizeof(ucHeap2) },
     { NULL, 0 } /* Terminates the array. */
};
int main() {
    return xHeapRegions[1].s;
}
EOF
```

Comment: How to make gcc produce error/warining about non-existent section?

Comment: I do not know. Most probably the simplest would be to create a list of allowed sections and list the section of generated executable and see it there are any sections not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

```
__attribute__((section("CCMRAM")));
```

you do not have section `CCMRAM`. You have section `.ccmram`.

Comment: linker is not even gcc. They do know about each other so it is not possible. Generate the map file and check

Comment: What to check in map file? What to search for?

Comment: for your variable